# Application takes different amount of memory on different systems

Tags: memory, docker, memory-management, cpu, cpu-speed

I have two systems with different Xeon processors and different amounts of RAM. Both run on Ubuntu 16 and have the same docker version. My applications are dockerized.

I ran the same docker image on both the systems and the amount of memory they consumed on both the systems are 610 MB and 814 MB.

I'm trying to figure out why this difference occurs. Does having a faster CPU reduce the usage of memory? and if so then why does it take less memory?

Comment: What does the application do?

Comment: I'm trying this with multiple applications, with similar results, these are database workloads, heavy computing mathematical operations etc.

Comment: I wonder if you have found the answer because I am curious too. I am running an application with neural networks on different machines, but the memory consumed are different.